# Symfony 2 and static resources

Tags: symfony

I am new to Symfony 2 and there is something I would like to know..

It looks like you have to put your static resources to this location: `MyBundle/Resources/public`

but if I want to use twig functions like `asset`, it is good if resources are at this location: `web/MyBundleName/`

Why do I have to duplicate my resources ? (one in the `src/MyBundle/Resources/public` and the other one in `web/MyBundle`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run [`app/console assets:install web`](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/templating.html#including-stylesheets-and-javascripts-in-twig) to copy resources from the activated bundles to the `web/bundles` folder.

This is not a duplication. The `web/bundles` folder is the place where all the assets from all the bundles are being installed to. The folder should be ignored by your VCS.

The reason for this approach is that 3rd party bundles — and the reusable bundles you'll create later — don't have access to the `web` folder of an application. Installing assets with the command solves this problem.

Comment: thank you for the command line but why do I have to duplicate ?